# Вывести первые 3 значения массива через ForEach

Tags: javascript

Необходимо при загрузке страницы вывести только первые 3 блока, это можно сделать через ForEach, но не могу понять как...

Есть массив

```
const hotels = [
    {
        title: "Albus Hotel Amsterdam City Centre",
        price: 115,
        photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/31881601.webp?k=25b6ebb4be040e97c397ac14ea706c37940679caed81ad3d8c4dddd1f10c71b2&o='
    },
    {
        title: 'Park Plaza Victoria Amsterdam',
        price: 150,
        photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/13334194.webp?k=194460badd8a74b28e1bf59aa917de049ed1c9e1ec252ad26aec1ba492b7f69e&o='
    },
    {
        title: 'Park Inn by Radisson Amsterdam City West',
        price: 95,
        photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/160590097.webp?k=4914b560022372de041f5e8ec2b257bdbbd318035848852193f0e64e04dd9402&o='
    },
    {
        title: 'NH City Centre Amsterdam',
        price: null,
        photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/260988043.webp?k=f080732cb7ec98a4724a49936da46f5c36fa00d31e78cc3c7cc6f51c9e50ed37&o='
    },
    {
        title: 'Mercure Amsterdam Sloterdijk Station',
        price: 54,
        photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/252169240.webp?k=09d57ae22ddc721dac84ccfbdf5433b8561e8995060b41128fb7271f79a075cc&o='
    },
    {
        title: 'Monet Garden Hotel Amsterdam',
        price: 102,
        photo: ''
    },
    {
        title: 'Radisson Blu Hotel, Amsterdam City Center',
        price: 154,
        photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/228897852.webp?k=7b11c21a67b4f8e847628b69e83b7245fe2698b704a2f8245f44a49de5eb814a&o='
    },
    {
        title: 'NH Collection Amsterdam Barbizon Palace',
        price: 172,
        photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/256888798.webp?k=03b5832921f7a206abdc69df10bcb91992fb14b614917e452bd082a2a1abf47e&o='
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `forEach` второй параметр отвечает за индекс элемента в массиве. Может использовать его для проверки, меньше ли он 3 или нет.

```js
const hotels = [ { title: "Albus Hotel Amsterdam City Centre", price: 115, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/31881601.webp?k=25b6ebb4be040e97c397ac14ea706c37940679caed81ad3d8c4dddd1f10c71b2&o=' }, { title: 'Park Plaza Victoria Amsterdam', price: 150, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/13334194.webp?k=194460badd8a74b28e1bf59aa917de049ed1c9e1ec252ad26aec1ba492b7f69e&o=' }, { title: 'Park Inn by Radisson Amsterdam City West', price: 95, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/160590097.webp?k=4914b560022372de041f5e8ec2b257bdbbd318035848852193f0e64e04dd9402&o=' }, { title: 'NH City Centre Amsterdam', price: null, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/260988043.webp?k=f080732cb7ec98a4724a49936da46f5c36fa00d31e78cc3c7cc6f51c9e50ed37&o=' }, { title: 'Mercure Amsterdam Sloterdijk Station', price: 54, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/252169240.webp?k=09d57ae22ddc721dac84ccfbdf5433b8561e8995060b41128fb7271f79a075cc&o=' }, { title: 'Monet Garden Hotel Amsterdam', price: 102, photo: '' }, { title: 'Radisson Blu Hotel, Amsterdam City Center', price: 154, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/228897852.webp?k=7b11c21a67b4f8e847628b69e83b7245fe2698b704a2f8245f44a49de5eb814a&o=' }, { title: 'NH Collection Amsterdam Barbizon Palace', price: 172, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/256888798.webp?k=03b5832921f7a206abdc69df10bcb91992fb14b614917e452bd082a2a1abf47e&o=' }, ];

hotels.forEach((e, i) => { if (i < 3) console.log(e); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, есть смысл использовать `every` вместо `foreach`, чтобы не проходить все элементы массива.

```js
const hotels = [ { title: "Albus Hotel Amsterdam City Centre", price: 115, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/31881601.webp?k=25b6ebb4be040e97c397ac14ea706c37940679caed81ad3d8c4dddd1f10c71b2&o=' }, { title: 'Park Plaza Victoria Amsterdam', price: 150, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/13334194.webp?k=194460badd8a74b28e1bf59aa917de049ed1c9e1ec252ad26aec1ba492b7f69e&o=' }, { title: 'Park Inn by Radisson Amsterdam City West', price: 95, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/160590097.webp?k=4914b560022372de041f5e8ec2b257bdbbd318035848852193f0e64e04dd9402&o=' }, { title: 'NH City Centre Amsterdam', price: null, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/260988043.webp?k=f080732cb7ec98a4724a49936da46f5c36fa00d31e78cc3c7cc6f51c9e50ed37&o=' }, { title: 'Mercure Amsterdam Sloterdijk Station', price: 54, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/252169240.webp?k=09d57ae22ddc721dac84ccfbdf5433b8561e8995060b41128fb7271f79a075cc&o=' }, { title: 'Monet Garden Hotel Amsterdam', price: 102, photo: '' }, { title: 'Radisson Blu Hotel, Amsterdam City Center', price: 154, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/228897852.webp?k=7b11c21a67b4f8e847628b69e83b7245fe2698b704a2f8245f44a49de5eb814a&o=' }, { title: 'NH Collection Amsterdam Barbizon Palace', price: 172, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/256888798.webp?k=03b5832921f7a206abdc69df10bcb91992fb14b614917e452bd082a2a1abf47e&o=' }, ];

hotels.every((e, i) => { console.log(e); return i < 2; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
const hotels = [ { title: "Albus Hotel Amsterdam City Centre", price: 115, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/31881601.webp?k=25b6ebb4be040e97c397ac14ea706c37940679caed81ad3d8c4dddd1f10c71b2&o=' }, { title: 'Park Plaza Victoria Amsterdam', price: 150, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/13334194.webp?k=194460badd8a74b28e1bf59aa917de049ed1c9e1ec252ad26aec1ba492b7f69e&o=' }, { title: 'Park Inn by Radisson Amsterdam City West', price: 95, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/160590097.webp?k=4914b560022372de041f5e8ec2b257bdbbd318035848852193f0e64e04dd9402&o=' }, { title: 'NH City Centre Amsterdam', price: null, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/260988043.webp?k=f080732cb7ec98a4724a49936da46f5c36fa00d31e78cc3c7cc6f51c9e50ed37&o=' }, { title: 'Mercure Amsterdam Sloterdijk Station', price: 54, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/252169240.webp?k=09d57ae22ddc721dac84ccfbdf5433b8561e8995060b41128fb7271f79a075cc&o=' }, { title: 'Monet Garden Hotel Amsterdam', price: 102, photo: '' }, { title: 'Radisson Blu Hotel, Amsterdam City Center', price: 154, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/228897852.webp?k=7b11c21a67b4f8e847628b69e83b7245fe2698b704a2f8245f44a49de5eb814a&o=' }, { title: 'NH Collection Amsterdam Barbizon Palace', price: 172, photo: 'https://cf.bstatic.com/xdata/images/hotel/square600/256888798.webp?k=03b5832921f7a206abdc69df10bcb91992fb14b614917e452bd082a2a1abf47e&o=' }, ];

hotels.slice(0, 3).forEach(hotel => {
  console.log(hotel.title);
});
```